# How to get Java8 Metaspace dump (not heap dump)

Tags: jvm, dump, metaspace

Are there any tools that are able to get Metaspace dump from a Java8 hotspot vm ?

Comment: In which form would you like to get this and what for? Note that data in Metaspace are not Java objects. Probably you're not interested in HotSpot internal structures, but in something else.

Comment: We have an application causes Metaspace OOM error with 1G of MaxMetaspaceSize, and I wanted to know how Metaspace memories are being used.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It seems you encounter a class loading leak.
Use

- `jmap -clstats PID` to dump class loader statistics;
- `jcmd PID GC.class_stats` to print the detailed information about memory usage of each loaded class. The latter requires `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions`.

The heap dump will also help, because each class in the Metaspace has a corresponding `java.lang.Class` instance in the heap.

Comment: Hi apangin, thanks for your advice. I was able to dump the entire heap using jmap -dump command, however I am struggling to run jhat command to analyze the dump file. The heap dump is about 5GB, and jhat has been running 2 hours  without completion, is this normal?

Comment: jhat eventually terminated with heap space OOM error after running about 2 hours.

Comment: @czh [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) works fine even with large heap dumps.

Comment: @czh You can also try VisualVM or YourKit for larger heaps.

Comment: How to interpret below statistics to know whether my fix of METASPACE OOM is working? Dump Reason : JCMD
MaxMetaspaceSize : 536870912 B
CompressedClassSpaceSize : 528482304 B
Class Space Used : 21412264 B
Class Space Capacity : 25373696 B
Class Space Committed : 44572672 B
Class Space Reserved : 1073741824 B
NonClass Spaces Used : 178477376 B
NonClass Spaces Capacity : 219028480 B
NonClass Spaces Committed : 347594752 B
NonClass Spaces Reserved : 348127232 B

Comment: I struggled to determine what was causing metaspace leaks in my project. I used jcmd PID GC.class_stats to identify the resident classes, then a heap dump + VisualVM to identify what (which GC root) was holding onto these unwanted classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to dig into what your metaspace allocations are, a more in depth option would be to use Native Memory Tracking. You would want to use detail level native memory tracking, which can be enabled by passing `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail` to the JVM. Then you can run

```
jcmd <pid> VM.native_memory baseline
```

To establish a baseline. Then after letting the JVM run until the problem should have reoccurred, you can run

```
jcmd <pid> VM.native_memory detail.diff
```

Then the `Class` allocations in the NMT diff will provide the metaspace allocations. The [orcale docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html) have more information on NMT.