# Metaspace of Java VM runs full

Tags: java, metaspace

I am trying to get my Java code to run, but whenever I try the metaspace starts to get full. At first I didn't even notice it since it takes a long time (~1 month) to run full and crash.

The first thing I did was to look into the code, if there were Objects being created and filled with a lot of data and not deleted by the GC. After determining that this was (most likely) not the case I wrote       a little test programm which results in the same error.

In my main I call a new TimerTask and assign a Timer to it. Afterwards I just schedule it.

```
TestTimer testTimerTask = new TestTimer();
Timer timer = new Timer("test");
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(testTimerTask, 0, 100);
```

And here the TimerTask itself which just creates a bunch of Objects that should be deleted      afterwards.

```
public class TestTimer extends TimerTask{
    private long x = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            if(x >= 2147483647) {
                x = 0;
            }
            str = new String("" + x);
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

So I tried *debugging* it. For this I used the 2.0.4 Version of [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/).
After letting it run for some time I got these two pictures of the [Metaspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpAkj.png) and the [Heap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0mik.png).

In addition here's my JVM arguments,

```
-Xms64m
-Xmx128m
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=./log4j2.xml
```

my JVM Version **OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.8+10, mixed mode)** and my Java Version **version 11.0.8, vendor Oracle Corporation**.

Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot this problem some more and to stop my metaspace from filling up?

Comment: When your app crashed, are you getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace` or something else?

Comment: @suv3ndu I stopped it before it did since there are other apps running on the same system.

Comment: Ok. In that case I will suggest you to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37933050/5334745) to get the Metaspace data periodically. Once you have that, you can analyze them to see what's growing over time.